# How to upload an image and then store it in a database?

Tags: php, file-upload

I am trying to Upload an image and store it in the database. I have mentioned the code, but it is not working for me. I'm not able to find the bug. Please see if anybody can find the bug.
The code is:

```
<?php

$name=$_REQUEST['name'];
$email=$_REQUEST['email'];

if($_REQUEST['submit'])
{
    if(($_FILES['file']['type']=="image/jpeg" or $_FILES['file']['type']=="image/pjpeg" or $_FILES['file']['type']=="image/gif") and ($_FILES['file']['size']<300000))
    {
        if($_FILES['file']['error']>0)
        {
            $err=" ERROR :: ".$_FILES['file']['error'];
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Upload :".$_FILES['file']['name']."<br/>";
            echo "Type: ".$_FILES['file']['type']."<br/>";
            echo "Size: ".($_FILES['file']['size']/1024)."Kb<br/>";
            echo "Stored in: ".$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']."<br/>";

            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],"upload/".$_FILES['file']['name']);
            echo $_FILES['file']['name'];
            echo $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']."qwerty";

            $n=3000;
            $fo=fopen("upload/".$_FILES['file']['name'],"r");
            $fr=fread($fo,$n);

            mysql_query("update user set pic='$fr' where id='$id'");

        }
    }
    else
    {
        $err=" ERROR :: Invalid Image";
    }

    mysql_query("update user set name='$name' where id='$id'");
    mysql_query("update user set email='$email' where id='$id'");


}

$sql="select * from user where id='$id'";
$con=mysql_query($sql);
list($idR,$nameR,$emailR,$pwdR,$dateR,$picR)=mysql_fetch_array($con);

?>



<body>
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><?php echo $err; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Name:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $nameR ?>" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Email:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $emailR ?>" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="file">Upload or Change Pic:</label></td>
            <td><input type="file" name="file" id="file" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save"/></td>
        </tr>

    </table>    
</form>
</body>
```

My code is not even able to upload the file. When I tried to `echo` the following, I found them empty:

```
   echo "Name:".$_FILES['file']['name']."<br/>";
   echo "Type: ".$_FILES['file']['type']."<br/>";
   echo "Size: ".($_FILES['file']['size']/1024)."Kb<br/>";
   echo "Stored in: ".$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
```

All the above fields are empty.

Comment: Is the file less than 300K? I also suggest you print_r($_FILES) right at the top and see what you get.

Comment: it is better to store image path in database and image in another folder or location

Comment: yes the file is less than 300K @Robbie.....

Comment: i'm not even getting the image in a folder (Folder name: upload, as mentioned in code)... if i'll get it in the folder then i could do what you suggested @vikrantx

Comment: `print_r($_FILES)` What does it yield in your case? Also does the folder `upload` have necessary permissions set?

Comment: print_r($_FILES) is showing an empty array...@Robbie

Comment: i'm getting this Warning... Warning: fopen(upload/) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in C:\wamp\www\blog\php\editp.php     what kind of permissions do i need to set and how?  @verisimiltude

Comment: And print_r($_POST) is also empty, per chance?

Comment: @Robbie.... print_r($_POST) is not empty... its showing... Array ( [name] => Sahil [email] => sahil@gmail.com [file] => pic.jpg [submit] => Save )

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It worked when I moved my code on an independent .php file. And when I needed to upload I gave the link to that page in which independent uploading code was written. I don't know the reason behind this but this is how I solved it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how this work but it didn't worked. I guess the problem is somewhere in my `HTML` code because the `$_FILES` values are none/empty. It is not retrieving the value from the form tag please check if my answer is incorrect to solve the problem or correct to how to solved this hard problem from science or other subject in computers and it form to been error or successfully.

Comment: I couldn't figure out what you are trying to say. I request the person whosoever has upvoted this answer please try to explain it to me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_FILES['file']['size'] > 0)
{
    // Data
    $file_name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $tmp_name  = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $file_size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
    $file_type = $_FILES['file']['type'];

    // Check
    $type   = array(
        'image/jpeg',
        'image/gif',
        'image/png',
    );
    $size   = 300000;

    if(in_array($file_type, $type) AND $file_size > $size)
    {
        echo 'Ooops! File type must be JPG, GIF or PNG. Or file size too big';
        exit();
    }

    // Is error?
    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
        echo 'Upload Error';
        exit();
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'File Name : '.$file_name.'<br />';
        echo 'File Size : '.($file_size / 1024).' Kb<br />';
        echo 'File Type : '.$file_type;
    }
} 
?>

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save"/>  
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If $_POST and $_FILES are both empty then you've exceeded the maximum post size ini ('post_max_size')

There are several settings in php.ini, including the maximum for an individual file ('upload_max_filesize'), and the maximum for all uploads ('post_max_size'). Make sure those ini settings are set correctly

Be careful of syntax if you hve edited it, it's picky when handling M, K or G (not KB, MB or GB), and don't exceed the bit size of your server, i.e. don't go above 4billion bytes on a 32 bit server.

---

Other causes of $_FILES being empty, but not $_POST. You don't have enough free space to upload your files, or you don't have permissions ot write to the temp directory. Check /tmp has enough space, and that you can write to it as apache/php user.

Comment: $_POST is not empty... permission or lack of free space may not be the case here because when i'm uploading an image in a separate php file where i hav written the similar code for uploading but not of other updates as mention in the above code, my image is uploaded with that separate file. but not with the above code.

Comment: There appears nothing wrong with the code (that I can see) and you say other examples work - so server is fine. Is that all your code, then, and not edited? Most likely issue now is that you've edited from your real source to a working version above. Check the enctype exists in the original source, check that you only have one opening <form> element and one 'name="file"' input etc. That's all I can think of. If available publicly (the html part, not the php) can you post a link?

Comment: the above code is exactly what i'm running on my server... and the html part is in the above code i hav posted...

Comment: Absolutely stumped, then. My only 'last gasp" would be to suggest putting a URL in the "action", but can't see how that would help. So it's what I call "back to first principles" - take a bit of code that works elsewhere on the server, check it works here, then edit one line at a time until you get the code you need. Then compare the difference. Sorry - your code's fine (unless we're both missing it) so really no other suggestion.

Comment: It worked when I moved my code on an independent `.php` file. And when I needed to upload I gave the link to that page in which independent uploading code was written. I don't know the reason behind this but this is how I solved it.

Answer (score -2):

hmm....
try to change this line

```
if($_REQUEST['submit'])
```

to be

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['submit']))
```

and i think, this code

```
if(($_FILES['file']['type']=="image/jpeg" or $_FILES['file']['type']=="image/pjpeg" or $_FILES['file']['type']=="image/gif") and ($_FILES['file']['size']<300000))
```

can be simplified into

```
if(ereg("jpeg|pjpeg|jpg|gif|png", $_FILES['file']['type']) AND $_FILES['file']['size']<300000)
```

Good luck...

Comment: i tried as u suggested.... but it didnt worked. I guess the problem is somewhere in my html code because the $_FILES values are empty... it is not retriving the values from the form tag... please check if you find the bug...

Comment: "Deprecated" means that PHP 5.3.0 no longer supports that function. You should treat ereg() as not existing anymore.